# Nginx: disable gzip on images

Tags: nginx, gzip

In my nginx conf I have which enabled gzip:

```
gzip on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/javascript;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_vary on;
```

However this also gzips my jpeg's which actually increases size. How can I, ideally with out using location, disable gzipping of images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't set `gzip_types image/jpeg` anywhere then nginx will never compress your jpegs, unless they have different content-type (like `text/plain`) in headers.

This may be due to one of the following reasons:

- You have `gzip_types image/jpeg` in configuration;
- Images returned with incorrect `content-type` header;
- They compressed by something outside of nginx;
- A tool that you're using for check is broken.